# Bootstrap Image Carousel not sliding in ASP.NET Core using MVC

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc

I been searching around for some help recently but none have solved my problem. My web application in ASP.NET Core has twitter-bootstrap & jQuery install and they are called properly. My Image Carousel is in the Index.cshtml file and using the code "@RenderBody()" in the _Layout.cshtml it loads the content of my Index.cshtml which has the Image Carousel. The Image Carousel is not sliding and I need help to allow the images slide in. Here are the full codes of the both files in my web application.

How do ensure that the Image Carousel slide in my web application? Thanks in advance!

_Layout.cshtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
        <title>ChoreBear - @ViewBag.Title</title>
        <link href="~/lib/twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true"/>
        <link href="~/css/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/baeab757ac.js" crossorigin="anonymous" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <!--Navigation toolbar-->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="~/img/logo_white.png" alt="ChoreBear Logo" title="ChoreBear"/>
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarChoices">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <!--List of items in the navigation toolbar-->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarChoices">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contactless Delivery | Task</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Locations</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign up/Log in</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" id="BecomeATaskerBtn">Become a Tasker</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <!--COVID-19 alert jumbotron-->
        <div class="jumbotron py-8 mb-0">
           <div class="container">
               <div class="row justify-content-center">
                   <div class="col=sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-1 my-auto">
                       <a><img class="img-jumbotron mr-auto" src="~/img/prevention.png"/></a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-7 col-xl-6 pt-4">
                       <h4>See our latest approach towards COVID-19</h4> 
                       <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Learn more</button></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div> 
        </div>

        <main role="main">
            @RenderBody();
        </main>

    <!--JQuery files rendered here-->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script href="~/lib/jquery/jquery.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script href="~/lib/popper.js/umd/popper.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script href="~/lib/twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script href="~/lib/font-awesome/js/all.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </body>


    <!--Footer Section-->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center text-center text-light">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <img src="~/img/logo_white.png" alt="ChoreBear"/>
                    <p>ChoreBear strives to provide the greatest household services and provide the best freelancing oppurtunity in the world</p>
                </div>

                <!--Contact us section-->
                <div class="col-md-4">
                   <hr class="bg-light">
                   <h5>Contact us</h5>
                   <hr class="bg-light">
                   <p><a href="tel:+60331220262">+603-3122 0262</a></p>
                   <p><a href="mailto:+chorebear@@gmail.com">chorebear.gmail.com</a></p>
                   <p>62, Jalan Palas 12</p>
                   <p>Taman Dato Hormat</p>
                   <p>Telok Panglima Garang, 42500</p>
                   <p>Kuala Langat, Selangor, Malaysia</p>
                </div>

                <!--Operation hours section-->
                <div class="col-md-4">
                   <hr class="bg-light">
                   <h5>Our hours</h5>
                   <hr class="bg-light">
                   <p>Monday - Thursday: 9am - 4.30pm</p>
                   <p>Friday: 8.30am - 4pm</p>
                   <p>Saturday - Sunday: Closed</p>
                   <p>Public Holidays: Closed</p>
                </div>

                <!--Service areas section-->
                <div class="col-md-4">
                   <hr class="bg-light">
                   <h5>Locations</h5>
                   <hr class="bg-light">
                   <p>United Kingdom</p>
                   <p>United States</p>
                   <p>Malaysia</p>
                   <p>Israel</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!--Socket for the website-->
    <div class="socket text-light text-center py-4">
        <p>&copy;<a href="https://www.chorebear.com">chorebear.com</a></p>
    </div>
</html>
```

Index.cshtml

```html
@page
@model MyApp.Namespace.IndexModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<!--Image carousel slider-->
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel-slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="1000">
        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <!--Carousel image-->
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="~/img/carousel/background2.jpg" alt="Decorating" class="w-100">
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="~/img/carousel/background3.jpg" alt="Plumbing" class="w-100">
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="~/img/carousel/background4.jpg" alt="Electricity Repair" class="w-100">
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="~/img/carousel/background5.jpg" alt="Becoming a Tasker" class="w-100">
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!--Image Carousel indicators-->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
```

Here's the directory of the files needed for the Image Carousel
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to the problem. My _Layout.cshtml has wrong html attribute which is

```html
<script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.slim.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Previously, it was "href" which is wrong and was not working.